# format.js not executing (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to add email confirmation when signing up users. Users have to fill out a form with their invitation code and email address, and then they get an email with an activation link.

So all I want to do is have it so when the user fills out the form, it submits the form and reloads the form so that it hides and displays the message "we sent you an email, please check and click the link" instead of reloading the entire page.

**signup.html.erb**

here I've added remote: true

`<%= form_tag(form_action, method: :get, remote: true, id: 'create-form') do %>`

**users_controller.rb**

the redirect works but format.js is an unknown format

```
def new 

... code checking params

if @user.user_email_confirmed
  render :new
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to signup_path(@user.name, email: @user.email) }
    format.js
  end
end
```

**new.js.erb**

```
$('#create-form').hide().after('');
$('.login-form').append('<p class="link-sent">We have sent an activation link to the email address you entered - please be sure to check your spam or trash folders. Please click that link to complete account activation.</p>');
```

not sure what I am missing, any ideas?

Comment: when you hit the "submit" button in your form are you sure your `new` action is called, I really do not think so!!

Comment: Please check if you have some `before_action` or any other callback in your controller that may be causing issues

Comment: I'm pretty sure the submit button calls new. The form action points to a  users#new route.

Comment: When I put a binding.pry in the new method it goes to the `respond_to` line

Comment: No, it does not have sense that your form points to the `new` action, and there is not other reason of why you get unknown format... Or you are missing details

Comment: If my answer was useful please consider select it as accepted answer, that way it's more likely that other people in the community will help you when you have other questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really do not think that the action the form is calling when submitting is your `new` action, it may be some `create` action in your controller.

So when you hit the "submit" button of your form it is sent through Ajax due to you have `remote: true` option, and the action it is calling does not have a `format.js` nor `js.erb` view, That's why you get unknown format.

Make sure which controller action is being called when you submit your form, then add the `format.js` and the proper `js.erb` view.

Please take a look to this [blog post](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/respond-to-without-all-the-pain//), it may be helpful.